# error message for mongoose schema type mismatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema definition for a property amount.

If I don't pass a number or pass something less than 10, I am able to get the correct error messages as specified.

But I get a **blank error message** if the type specified is not number. For e.g. if I pass 'somestring'. It rightfully errors out on save, but with no message. Where can I specify the **error message for type mismatch**?

var ExpenseSchema = new Schema({

```
amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: 'Please fill Expense amount',
    min: [10, 'Please enter at least 10'],
    ....
```

Comment: I tried adding a custom validator function and assigning it to the validate attribute, but unfortunately if there is a type mismatch, that function is never called. It errors out before calling the validator.

Comment: Figured it out.. actually the following error is returned. But looks like the server code is eating up that error message."Cast to number failed for value "123g" at path "amount"

Comment: If you are using the meanjs stack, you might run into this as well.